Division in Tableau using "a selected number" from one column / COUNTD from another
I'm trying to do some division in Tableau but can't figure out a way to do it with the format the data is in.
I am using data that looks like this:

I need use the already summed "Total Members by Team" (Column D: Blue 37, Yellow 1053) and divide them by the Distinct ID count in Column A.
So there'd be two actual calculations, one for each team:
Team Blue: 37 / 3 = 12.3
Team Yellow: 1053 / 2 = 526.5
I can't figure out how to use only the specific corresponding Member count in column D for the division. I looked at other answers of somewhat similar questions, and it looks like the FIXED function would come in use here, but not sure how to implement (if it is indeed relevant).
Is there a way to write a Calculated Field and selectively use only the relevant Teams Member count for the division?

I have been requested to create a Worksheet in Tableau that looks like this:

